# where am I going wrong with this function?

Tags: c++, vector, palindrome

So i'm supposed to Move all palindrome numbers from mValues vector to mPalindromes vector

and the only hints I was given was a pseudo code:
//          iterate through the main values vector
//          if the value is a palindrome
//          add it to the palindrome vector
//          remove it from the values vector

and this is what I came up with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mValues.size(); i++)
    {
        if (IsPalindromeNumber(mValues[i]) )
        {
            mPalindromes.push_back(mValues[i]);

            mValues.pop_back();

            
        }
    }
```

If anyone could tell me where I went wrong I would appreciate it.

edit: I figured it out the problem was I was using erase instead of popback.

Comment: You were given IsPalindromNumber?

Comment: @AndrewCheong yes i was given the function IsPalindromeNumber, it checks if the number is a Palindrome

Comment: Shouldn't it be `+i` instead of `+1`?

Comment: @Jorengarenar ok so i just made that correction it did not work

Comment: @Jorengarenar did it im new to stack so idk how to do some stuff yet

Comment: Can you please add the test cases that fail for this code?

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
mValues.erase(mValues.begin() + i); // with correction from comments
```

you modify `mValues`, so `i` starts indexing elsewhere in `mValues`. One fix would be

```
mValues.erase(mValues.begin() + i);
i--;
```

but it's not very elegant. It would be better to copy the palindromes to `mPalindromes` and then use `std::remove_if` or something, in a second pass.

Comment: Hmm... If only there were some [combination of `copy` and `remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) :)